# Почему mobx не обновляет value у динамических input?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react-lite

Input успешно записывает данные в mobx 
При удалении input, mobx успешно удаляет данные. 
**Но почему value у оставшихся input остается прежним?**

*Пример.*
*Ожидается value 3, но он остается 1*
[Песочница с простым кодом](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dadata-sha1cn?file=src%2Fdadata.js,src%2Fstorage.js,src%2FApp.js)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что не надо использовать индекс в качестве ключа.

А mobx вообще не при чём.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что лучше использовать в качестве ключа? 
Потому что некоторые поля в форме могут быть одинаковыми, отчего может быть повторение.

Comment: @VanilJS, уникальный id из базы.

Comment: @VanilJS, ну генерировать id при создании объекта.

Comment: Хороший тон будет для всех генерировать уникальный ключ в виде timestamp функцией в storage mobx? function createUnic() { return +new Date() }

Comment: @VanilJS, при одновременном создании нескольких объектов может получиться одно и то же значение. Докинь ещё рандома.